# Return records from select based on column value. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

So i do have select witch looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE ID = 3933185`

Records witch select returns to me are:

```
ID          VALUE   ATTR_VALUE
3,933,185   1           1
3,933,185   1           1
3,933,185   1           1
3,933,185   1           2
3,933,185   1           2
```

As you can see per `attr_value` column there could be different values, `1` or `2`, nothing more.

So what should i add to make a check, when `attr_value` exists with value `1`, then it will return records where `attr_value = 1`, in other case it will return where `attr_value = 2`.

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value = (select min(t2.value) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

You can also use analytic functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(t.value) over (partition by id) as min_value
      from t
     ) t
where value = min_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use exists logic here:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM database1 d1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM database1 d2
                  WHERE d1.ID = d2.ID AND d2.ATTR_VALUE > d1.ATTR_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I followed you correctly, you can use analytical functions:

```
select id, value, attr_value
from (select t.*, rank() over(order by attr_value) rn from mytable t) t
where rn = 1
```